# after changing file from unix to dos it is having empty lines..how to handle this

Tags: unix

After converting file using `**unix2dos**` command it is having some empty lines. Please help me. How to handle this?

I tried to delete empty lines as follow, but couldn't work.

`$ sed '/^$/d' /tmp/data.txt`

Hey following examples also didn't work. Pl help

This is source data before using unix2dos.

```
ID NAME DATE

1 BALA 09/23/2013

2 KRISHH 09/24/2013

3 billy 09/24/2013
```

After using unix2dos it is coming as

```
ID NAME DATE

1 BALA 09/23/2013




2 KRISHH 09/24/2013

3 billy 09/24/2013
```

first and second record there is an empty line coming up..may be in bewteen data also

Thanks

Comment: Does `sed '/^\s*$/d'` work ?

Answer (score 0):

As you've mentioned your file has `CR-LF` line endings.  As such, `sed '/^$/d` wouldn't work.

Try

```
sed '/^\x0D$/d' inputfile
```

Comment: hey...sorry it didn't work...

Comment: Try `sed '/^\s*$/d'` as [commented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19025372/after-changing-file-from-unix-to-dos-it-is-having-empty-lines-how-to-handle-thi/19025525?noredirect=1#comment28111838_19025372)

Comment: sorry..this one also didn't work..why unix2dos command is ging empty lines

Comment: @user2814717 Post some lines of input before and after issuing `unix2dos`.  Update your question with the information.